# CSS Center full width navagation bar <ul> content

Tags: html, css, navbar, menubar

I am trying to center then float:right my top fixed navbar with the content area of my page. Currently the navbar is floated right but is not centered with my content area.

Click to view my [subject site](http://usplumbingshop.com).

CSS

```css
#topribbon{
width: 100%; 
height: 30px; 
background-color: #AA1119 ; 
margin: -11px 0px 1em 0px; 
position: fixed; 
z-index: 9999; 
}
#topribbon ul{

padding-top:5px;
text-align:right;
float:right;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:980px;
}

#topribbon ul li{
float:right;
color:white;
padding:0 10px 0 10px;
list-style:none;
display:block;
line-height:20px;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
width:auto;
}

#topribbon ul li:hover{
color:#5C8FA5;
```

HTML

```html
<div id="topribbon">  <ul>
        <li>Free Ground Shipping on all orders over $99!</li>
        <li>Why Us?</li>
        <li>Account</li>
        <li>Cart</li>
        <li>+1-800-555-5555</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is the width of **ul** element doesn't work.

Try this instead

```
<div id="topribbon">  
    <div class="ribbonwrapper" style="width:980px;margin:0 auto;">    
     <ul> 
         <li>Free Ground Shipping on all orders over $99!</li>
         <li>Why Us?</li>
         <li>Account</li>
         <li>Cart</li>
         <li>+1-800-555-5555</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Put the style of .ribbonwrapper into CSS to make the code tidy :) then you can remove irrelevant width & margin property of **#topribbon ul**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but if what you want is to float:right the UL and then have all the LI's within it centered, you could do this:

`#topribbon ul { float:right; text-align: center; }`

`#topribbon ul li { display: inline-block; }`

Be sure to remove the `float:right;` from the li style block.

If you mean something else by "centered with my content area" can you explain more?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by centered AND float right. It seems a bit contradictory to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `float:none;` on the `#topribbon ul`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty confused what you mean exactly myself... Maybe this is what you want? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ujJc/5/)**

```css
#topribbon {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #AA1119;
    margin: -11px 0px 1em 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#topribbon ul {
    padding:10px 0 8px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:980px;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#topribbon ul li {
    color:white;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:auto;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    float:right;
}
#topribbon ul li:hover {
    color:#5C8FA5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like others have said use the ul below. I am just as stumped as you however, I am new so if my code is wrong then please feel free to tell me. Thanks

```
#topribbon ul { float:right; text-align: center; }

#topribbon ul li { display: inline-block; }
```